# Node function on AWS Lambda can't connect to database with node-pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-postgres

My function works locally, but, when I deploy to AWS Lambda, it can't seem to connect to my postgres database. Here's the error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED] code: 'ECONNREFUSED', errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect' }, isOperational: true, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect' }
```

My database is hosted on an Azure virtual machine, and I'm not having problems connecting to it from any other app nor from this app when run locally. What could be causing the connection to fail when running on Lambda?

Comment: Some sort of firewall?

Comment: @Michelem Amazon says they limit traffic on TCP port 25 and that they limit outbound traffic to TCP. They manage inbound. I changed my connection string from `postgres://` to `tcp://` but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: You should try to nmap the Postgres port from the lambda server check if you can reach it: `nmap -p 5432 <postgres-hostname>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be something dumb. I am using node-lambda and thought the .env file it creates was propagated to the function's environment. Logging my DB connection string showed this wasn't the case. Once I set that, everything was golden.